# How to check if X-Content-Type-Options work?

Tags: http-headers

We have set request header `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` in a sample application.
To test it, I set a rule to change the content type of a js url from `application/javascript` to `text/css` through chrome app `Requestly`.
I was expecting that since the `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` is set, it should not allow the content type to change.
But when I run the application and check in Chrome developer tools for the js file url headers, I can see the new content type `text/css` and also error for executing the js file.
So I am wondering why it allowed the content type to change and if I am testing it the proper way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the response headers include "x-content-type-options: nosniff" by running:

```
curl -I <URL_TO_VERIFY>
```

Answer (score 0):

`X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` will prevent the browser from performing MIME sniffing, it can not prevent any other entities, like a browser extension or proxies, from altering content-type.

[MIME sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#MIME_sniffing) definition from MDN.

> In the absence of a MIME type, or in some other cases where a client
>   believes they are incorrectly set, browsers may conduct MIME sniffing,
>   which is guessing the correct MIME type by looking at the resource.
>   Each browser performs this differently and under different
>   circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command below, but it doesn't work for me.
`curl -I <URL_TO_VERIFY>`

But this syntax works for me:
`curl  '*' -I <URL_TO_VERIFY>`

If you run behind your company proxy:
`curl  --noproxy '*' -I <URL_TO_VERIFY>`